# Excel Filter operation

Tags: excel, filter

In my excel there is a column with values from 1-1000. I want to filter few values from these . Is there any option to pass the values by entering the values, instead of deselecting all and click the numbers that i need.

Comment: You might find the `Advanced Filter` useful.  You could set up criteria and have them refer to other cell(s) where you list the values you want to filter.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific on the filter criteria? .

On a general note:

1. Select any cell within the range.
2. Select Data -> Filter. You have the options you need.

Comment: I want to filter nunbers 5,10,400,350...etc upto 20 columns.